# Time complexity and algorithm speedup

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, time-complexity, space-complexity

Code take more than 1 sec when

> Constraints 1≤T≤10^5 1≤P≤10^5 1≤H≤10^6

How can I reduce the time taken by my code

```
# cook your dish here
def check(h, p):
    while p>0:
        if h<=0:
            return 1
        if h-p>=0:
            h = h-p
        else:
            h=0
        p = p/2
        # print(h,p)
    return 0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    h, p = map(int, input().split())
    print(check(h,p))
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `time-complexity` and `space-complexity`?

Comment: There is no `T` in this code.

Comment: What is the ques? no question given, what do u want to execute?

Comment: What exactly is `check` supposed to do? It seems there's a closed form expression that you could compute in O(1) time.

Comment: T similar to _ in last 3rd line. I am new in coding. My code show TLE. check function suppose to compute t and p values with some condition